# str_ireplace doesn't handle cyrillic text

Tags: php, php-7.4

I know and saw multiple questions asked on stackoverflow, but nobody had a solution and there is a real problem.

I have a chat and a filter to clear stop-words from it. Words can be arabic/russian/english/etc.

Let's say "hi" is a stop-word and should be replaced with some replacer.

```
$input = "Hi how are u";
$output = str_ireplace(['hi'], 'hello', $input);
echo $output; // hello how are u
```

So this code works as expected, but with russian:

```
$input = "Привет как дела";
$output = str_ireplace(['привет'], 'здравствуйте', $input);
echo $output; // Привет как дела
```

It doesn't work.

I have enabled mb_string extension, but there is no mb_str_ireplace() function. I saw in the internet (especially stackoverflow) that people are creating their own mb_str_ireplace() function with PHP, I'm not sure it's a good idea as it can have performance issues with big texts and a lot of stop-words.

Comment: `mb_eregi_replace('привет|hi', 'здравствуйте', $input);` works, i.e., multi-byte case-insensitive regular expression replace with a list separated by `|` instead of a `[]` list. Performance-wise this should be fine, regular expressions are highly optimized.